# Is it possible to change the format of the training output in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, format, tensorflow2.0

While training a Keras' model, Keras prints out a line showing e.g. the loss and the value of the metrics. For example, something like this.

```
39/1000 [>.............................] - ETA: 4:39 - loss: 63694.8726 - metric_0: 0.0000e+00 - metric_1: 0.0000e+00 - metric_2: 0.0000e+00T - ...
```

The problem is that this line can be very long if you have many metrics. Is there a way of formatting this line? It would be nice if we could format this line in a similar way we can format a string in Python with e.g. the `format` method.

Here's a [related Github issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2850).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `verbose=0` and print your own results in a callback.

Example:

```
from keras.callbacks import LambdaCallback

def printLog(epoch, logs):
    #get the metrics inside the `logs` variable
    #print whatever you want the way you want

printerCallback = LambdaCallback(on_epoch_end=printLog)

model.fit(........, callbacks = [printerCallback], verbose=0)
```

The downside is that you can't have an updating bar, you have one print per epoch.

Comment: We can also have a callback for `on_batch_end`, in case we want a more verbose output.

Comment: Yes, but usually this is way too much output. Unless you know how to make a cool updating bar like that. (If you do, I'd like to know :p)

Comment: In my case, the `on_epoch_end` is probably sufficient. I will confirm that this solution works and then eventually accept it, but maybe this could be a feature request.